# What can we say about the rank of the sum of a multiple of the identity matrix and a symmetric rank-$1$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Suppose we have the following symmetric matrix.

$$A = \sigma^2 I + u u^T$$

What can we say about the eigendecomposition of $A$?

Comment: By inspection, $Au = (\sigma^2 + \|u\|^2) u$ and $Av = \sigma^2 v$ for any $v$ orthogonal to $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you assuming that your rank one matrix is of the form $uu^T$ ? Your question suggests so, but your title does not.

If it's the case, then, $uu^T$ is symmetric, so, up to diagonalisation, it is diagonal.
Now, it has rank one, so its eigenvalues are 0 (of degree $n-1$) and some number $\alpha$, which is thus equal to the trace of the matrix. Direct computation shows that this trace is equal to $\sum u_i^2=\|u\|_2^2$. Finally, up to diagonalisation, $uu^T=Diag(\|u\|_2^2,0,...,0)$.

This gives $A=Diag(\|u\|^2+\sigma^2,\sigma^2,...,\sigma^2)$.
This gives you the rank, the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes,  rank one matrix is of the form $uu^T$.